# Checkbox does not get checked

Tags: selenium, webdriver, wait

Hi I am automating a webpage which contains multiple checkbox.
It clicks on a some checkbox and misses some checkbox.
This is my code.
Should I put a wait statement before the click to avoid this problem.

```
  IWebElement ClickElement = Wait.Until((d) => webDriver.FindElement(By.Id(parameter1)));
  ClickElement.Click();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try making this change in your code -

In wait until function you are checking if the element exists by using `findElement(By.Id(parameter1))`

After finding the WebElement check if this is displayed by using `isDisplayed()` method with in the waitUntil function.

You can also check if it has already checked or not by using `isSelected()` method.